# last time file opened

Tags: files, ls, date

Is it possible to get the time when file was opened last time and sort all files in a directory by those times?

Answer (score 246, accepted):

This depends on exactly what you mean by "opened", but in general, yes. There are three timestamps normally recorded:

- `mtime` — updated when the file contents change. This is the "default" file time in most cases.
- `ctime` — updated when the file *or* its metadata (owner, permissions) change
- `atime` — updated when the file is read

So, generally, what you want to see is the `atime` of a file. You can get that with `stat` or with `ls`. You can use `ls -lu` to do this, although I prefer to use `ls -l --time=atime` (which should be supported in almost all modern Linux distributions) because I don't use it often, and when I do I can remember it better. And to *sort* by time, add the `-t` flag to ls. So there you go.

There is a big caveat, though. Updating the atime every time a file is read causes a lot of usually-unnecessary IO, slowing everything down. So, most Linux distributions now default to the `noatime` filesystem mount option, which basically kills atimes, or else `relatime`, which only updates atimes once a limit has passed (normally once per day) or if the file was actually modified since the previous read. You can find if these options are active by running the `mount` command.

Also, note that access times are by inode, not by filename, so if you have hardlinks, reading from one will update all names that refer to the same file.

And, be aware that *c* is not "creation"; creation isn't tracked by Unix/Linux filesystems, which seems strange but actually makes sense because the filesystem has no way of knowing if it is the original — maybe the file was created forty years ago and copied here. And, in fact, many file editors work by making copies over the original. If you need that information, it's best to use a version control system like `git`.

---

A little update, a decade later: some filesystems, like btrfs, include a fourth timestamp:

- `birth`, or sometimes but not consistently, `btime` — this is explicitly a "file creation timestamp"

... at least, in the `statx(2)` system call man page. It seems to be pretty sparsely documented overall. It really suffers from the same problem that made it get left out in the first place: what *exactly* does it mean? Consider:

```
$ echo > foo; stat foo|grep Birth
 Birth: 2022-04-30 02:38:19.084919920 -0400
$ cp foo foo.tmp; mv foo.tmp foo; stat foo|grep Birth
 Birth: 2022-04-30 02:39:00.950269045 -0400
```

Here, I've created a file, and then copied it to a temporary file, and then moved that back. This changes the "birth" time. Is that right? Maybe! I'm not sure that's really useful, at least not for humans. But anyway, for completeness: that's a thing you might have available on a modern system.

Comment: I'd give you more than +1 if I could, simply for not calling ctime "Creation Time".

Comment: According to the mount manpage, *relatime* has nothing to do with daily limits, but only looks at the atime *relative* to mtime and ctime. If atime is older than mtime or ctime, atime is updated. If atime is newer than both, then it is left alone. The purpose of this is to preserve the *relation* between atime and mtime / ctime, since some applications use that information, like mutt to see if it has read your mailbox since it was last updated.

Comment: @jw013 This has been the case since the 2.6.30 kernel. It's true that some older distributions may not have this behavior. (But for distributions like Fedora, it was true even back when I wrote the original version of this answer three years ago.) Look for an updated `mount` manpage.

Comment: `ls` shortens the time by default to a sensible precision. To see the time in full precision one can use `--full-time`.

Comment: $ ls -l --time=mtime
ls: invalid argument ‘mtime’ for ‘--time’
Valid arguments are:
  - ‘atime’, ‘access’, ‘use’
  - ‘ctime’, ‘status’
Try 'ls --help' for more information.

Comment: what happened to mtime?

Comment: @MonaJalal mtime is the default for `ls`. The `--time` parameter really only has options for `ctime` or `atime`, with the other arguments ("access", "use", "status") just being synonyms.

Answer (score 29):

`ls -ltu` list all the files, showing and sorting by access time.

From `man ls`:

```
-u     with -lt: sort by, and show, access time with -l: show access
       time and sort by name otherwise: sort by access time
```

Answer (score 4):

The `find` command is best for this. See the `-ctime`, `-mtime`, and `-atime` options

Answer (score 3):

If your listing is for human consumption, use `ls` with one of the date sorting flags (`-tu` for access (read) time, just `-t` for modification (write) time or `-tc` for inode change time). See [mattdm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8840/last-time-file-opened/8842#8842) for more information (in particular the caveat regarding `-a` and the definition of `-c`).

If this is for program consumption, [parsing the output of `ls` is problematic](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If your shell is zsh, you don't need `ls` anyway: zsh has globbing qualifiers to sort the matches by increasing access (`*(Oa)`), inode change (`*(Oc)`) or modification (`*(Om)`) time. A lowercase `o` sorts by increasing age.

```
act_on_files_by_date *(Om)
```

Otherwise, if you know that the file names don't contain any newline or non-printable characters (in the current locale), then you can do something like

```
ls -t | while read -r name; do act_on_one_file "$name"; done
ls -t | xargs -I {} act_on_one_file {}
```

If you want to invoke a command on many files at once, you need more setup. Note that `act_on_files_by_date $(ls -t)` doesn't work just like this, as filenames containing wildcard characters or whitespace would be expanded in the result of the command substitution. The following code works as long as no filename contains a newline or a non-printable character:

```
IFS='
'
set -f
act_on_files_by_date $(ls -t)
set +f
unset IFS
```

If you want to cope with arbitrary file names, you'll have a very hard time without resorting to more powerful tools than a standard shell: zsh, perl, python…

Answer (score 0):

The following command sort the files according to their access time i.e. atime.

```
ls -lt --time atime
```