# Will rsync restore original file metadata?

Tags: rsync, file-metadata

Goal: synch a large number of large files (filesize>500MB) from one NAS (WD Mycloud) to another. rysnc is available on both. Both are connected via a Gigabit switch. NAS files can be moved with Windows Explorer at 40+MB/s, however the file metadata (dates) are changed to the current date. rsync runs at ~10-12MB/s.

If the files were copied with Windows Explorer (for speed) the data's creation date would reflect today's date.  Could the file date creation and other related file meta-data be restored with a specific rsync option to match the source files?

Update: I have been advised by @RomeoNinov to update this question: An attempt to use rsync was half-successful and restored the dates of files, but not the folders.

```
rsync -ax --size-only --progress root@192.168.8.109:/shares/Public/Drivers /shares/Public
```

I was advised that adding -v to the statement and [this link would help explain why it was not changed.](http://andreafrancia.it/2010/03/understanding-the-output-of-rsync-itemize-changes.html)  My attempt to decode was not successful.

The request is for a command line example (similar to above) that will sync the files and folder meta-data.   Looking forward to clever responses and a good narrative.

Comment: For reference, the `rsync` specifics relating to speed are (also) being discussed at [Diagnosing a rsync bottleneck](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306880/diagnosing-a-rsync-bottleneck).

Comment: I guess you are using Explorer to copy locally between two (network) mount points but you are using rsync via ssh - that's slow. Try to use ```rsync``` (or just ```cp```) like you use the Explorer.

Comment: @rudimeier  My gut tells me you have something, however, I did not udnerstand and am confused.  Could you clarify with a command line example?  Thanks

Comment: @gatorback Your rsync command line connects via ssh protocol to your NAS box. ssh is encrypted and slow because your NAS box probably does not have much cpu power. Your Explorer is probably just copying files from one "windows network drive" to another "windows network drive"  (both smb protocol), thats much faster. So you should ```mount``` both of your NAS box shares via smb or nfs on your linux box. And then try ```rsync -a --size-only /mnt/shares1/...  /mnt/shares2/ ``` (local, no IP adresses or hostnames).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `rsync -aX` to have it sync the metadata (including permissions and timestamps — adjust flags as necessary to sync what you want), and `--size-only` to disable checking the timestamps for the quick-check algorithm. From the man page:

> `--size-only`
>             This  modifies rsync’s "quick check" algorithm for finding files
>             that need to be transferred, changing it  from  the  default  of
>             transferring  files  with  either  a  changed  size or a changed
>             last-modified time to just looking for files that  have  changed
>             in  size.  This is useful when starting to use rsync after using
>             another mirroring  system  which  may  not  preserve  timestamps
>             exactly.

... which sounds like basically your situation. There is the possibility, of course, of missing some change which updated the file but left it the same size (say, switching some words around) — but if you're sure you run it right after the copy with no chance of the source files changing, that won't be an issue.

Note, though, that Unix has no standard "creation" date. (See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8842/2511).) I don't know this will interact with whatever filesystem and metadata your NAS uses and provides.

Comment: @rudimeier Sure — updated to say "no standard" instead of "no".

Comment: Excited to see that the files were changes, but unsure why the folders were not changed.  Not sure if should create a new thread or answer.  rsync -axn --size-only --progress root@192.168.8.109:/shares/Public/Drivers /shares/Public

Comment: To understand the `rsync` process add a few `-v` (verbosity) flags and use http://andreafrancia.it/2010/03/understanding-the-output-of-rsync-itemize-changes.html to understand the log output. That should help you understand why certain changes are not being propagated.